# Will gcc remove unused class field, in the final executable file?

Tags: c++, g++

For example, will gcc/g++(version 9.4, or 7.3) remove unused `c` and `pc` in the output file, because this piece of code access only `C::i` and `C::j`, but not `C::c` and`C::pc`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
  
struct C {
    // i, j is used below
    int i;
    int j;
    // c, pc is not used
    char c;
    char *pc;
    C() : i(2) {}
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.j = 9;
    std::cout << c.j << c.i << sizeof(c) << std::endl;
}
```

---

---

The problem I am confused with is almost solved, inspired by the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118068/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-structs?rq=4).

Now I understand that the field is accessed as a pointer plus an offset, thus without an access, there will be no code representing as such a pointer plus an offset, in the final executable file.

Comment: Read about [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65026120/why-adjacent-members-of-the-same-type-can-have-padding-in-between). Also see dupe: [How to get rid of padding bytes between data members of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277842/how-to-get-rid-of-padding-bytes-between-data-members-of-a-struct)

Comment: [The size of a structure is a multiple of the alignment requirement of a data member with the largest alignment requirement.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242042/12002570)

Comment: What would it mean to "remove unused class fields"? How would you know whether gcc "removed" them? At least the value of `sizeof(c)` must be computed as if the members are present. Do the fields now count as used or as unused in your book?

Comment: in the code you posted `c` and `pc` are not "unused". Its just comments. Comments are only relevant for human readers but not for anything else

Comment: The compiler will ignore comments.  The comments will not generate code, and will not show up in the `sizeof c` operator.

Comment: Not sure this is really a duplicate or even about padding. Are you saying that the `sizeof(c)` gives the same output with or without the `char *pc;` line commented-out?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are right, and I just re-posted the code.

Comment: @AdrianMole The problem I am confused with actually is almost solved, inspired by the this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118068/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-structs?rq=4. What I am concerned with is the size of the executable file, and will the fields cause an increasing of the size.

Comment: This question is not related to padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilers will not optimize out unused `struct` fields. In theory they might be allowed (but not required) to do so, but in practice it never happens. One reason is that the compiler normally sees only one translation unit at a time, and can never be sure that the field is not accessed in other translation units.